# How to update a single record in VF page using REST API?

Tags: visualforce, rest-api

How to update a single record in VF page using REST API on click of a button?

The requirement is to update an account status on click of a button. I dont want to use apex controller . Want to do it using javascript so thought of rest api.

Comment: can you please post some code here so that its clear why we need to update through REST API?

Comment: Can you say why you want to use the REST API?

Comment: JavaScript remoting (@RemoteAction method in the controller) would be the appropriate way to go, I think: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_js_remoting.htm

Comment: @metadaddy So can JS Remoting controllers be called from Custom Button JavaScript?

Comment: @AndrewFawcett - yes - you can put the RemoteAction method in a controller extension.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <script src="/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js"></script>
 <script>
 var contactId = "{!Contact_ID}";
    function initPage() {
       try{
           var contact = sforce.connection.retrieve("Phone",[contactId])[0];
           contact.Phone = "12398238";
           result = sforce.connection.update([account]);
      if (result[0].getBoolean("success")) {
         log("account with id " + result[0].id + " updated");
     } else {
      log("failed to update account " + result[0]);
     }

    }

  }

</script>
```

Please follow the above for how to approach using purely java script.Note with ajaz toolkit you don't need REST API at all .

I don't recommend using JavaScript or ajax toolkit for this requirement or using any REST API  .A simple visualforce page with an extension controller would do the needful